# How to install /bin and /lib folder of a extracted .tar.gz file properly?

Tags: software-installation

I have download the .tar.gz archive of Robo3T and ended up with a `/bin` and a `/lib` and several other directories. How am I supposed to install this now? I do not wanna just copy them in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib` because I don't know what I might destroy that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `robot3t` without copying files/directories:

```
cd robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406/bin/
./robot3t
```

tarball on github: [robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406.tar.gz](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/releases)

You can create a symlink:

```
ln -s robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406/bin/robo3t  ~/.local/lib
robo3t
```

Comment: yea but I'd love to have it available in the /bin so I can use it from everywhere

Comment: @xetra11 create a symbolic link

Answer (score -1):

Where dos that tar file come from? How was it created? What are the exact contents `tar tf` should tell). With GNU tar there is the option `--strip-components=N` to strip N components from the start of the extracted files, N = 1 should strip the offending `/`.

Test before trusting random strangers on the 'net! Their setup might be different, they make mistakes/assumptions that aren't valid, ...